# Key out everything but one color?

Tags: premiere, chromakey

Ok I know this might be very basic for many of you, but I couldn't quite figure out how to do this ...

So, in case I want something like a reverse color keying where everything *except* one particular color is keyed out, what would be the easiest or, even better, most customizable way to do this in Premiere Pro?

I want to be able to manually set the tolerance level for similar colors as well as soft edges.

Thanks in advance!

No answers starting with "This is much easier with After Effects ..." please!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is quite simple.  Use any keyer of your choice that can give you a good mask for the layer, then place an "Alpha Adjust" layer below it in the Effects control and click the "Invert Alpha" checkbox.  This will invert the alpha channel produced by the keyer and reverse the effect the way you are looking for.

[image]

Comment: If your image is RGBA composed of image that have R/G/B mask and Alpha transparency, you can't as invert alpha will also invert the alpha and not only the R or G or B mask.

Comment: @softyodayoann I specified to create an alpha mask and then invert it to swap which side is transparent and which is not.  Invert alpha will only invert the alpha channel.

Answer (score 0):

Not specific to Premiere, but the general technique is: Set up the key to drop out the color of choice, then invert the key.

Comment: Would have done that, but the ultra key didn't seem to have a invert option. Or maybe I overlooked it?